# TCP connection reset due to multiple acknoledgement from server?

Tags: sockets, tcp, nio

I am trying to have a tcp communication established between a gps device and java asynchronous nio socket channel.
When the server reads from the channel after accepting the connection, it gives the below stack trace.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
>           at sun.nio.ch.PendingFuture.get(PendingFuture.java:185)
>               at com.socket.Teltonika.Codec.NioSocketServer$1.completed(NioSocketServer.java:50)
>              at com.socket.Teltonika.Codec.NioSocketServer$1.completed(NioSocketServer.java:32)
>               at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
>               at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
>               at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
>               at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
>               at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
>               at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
>               at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
>               at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:387)
>               at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:191)
>               at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
>               at sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:293)

When I look at the tcpdump , I find that there is a reset connection from the client. Under what conditions can this happen?
Also I see that the server is sending ack twice, could this be a problem.??
x.x.x.x -- Gps device ip
y.y.y.y -- My server ip

> 17:29:38.129012 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 115, id 43952, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
>       x.x.x.x.live.vodafone.in.43187 > y.y.y.y.4241: Flags [S], cksum 0xa168 (correct), seq 1477993782, win 10880, options [mss 1348,nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,nop,TS val 983851 ecr 0], length 0
>
> 17:29:38.129056 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
>       y.y.y.y.4241 > x.x.x.x.live.vodafone.in.43187: Flags [S.], cksum 0xf0e9 (incorrect -> 0x92e7), seq 1324366009, ack 1477993783, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1043927932 ecr 983851,nop,wscale 7], length 0
>
> 17:29:39.127403 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
>       y.y.y.y.4241 > x.x.x.x.live.vodafone.in.43187: Flags [S.], cksum 0xf0e9 (incorrect -> 0x91ed), seq 1324366009, ack 1477993783, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1043928182 ecr 983851,nop,wscale 7], length 0
>
> 17:29:41.127397 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
>       y.y.y.y.4241 > x.x.x.x.live.vodafone.in.43187: Flags [S.], cksum 0xf0e9 (incorrect -> 0x8ff9), seq 1324366009, ack 1477993783, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1043928682 ecr 983851,nop,wscale 7], length 0
>
> 17:29:42.113169 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 115, id 43953, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
>       x.x.x.x.live.vodafone.in.43187 > y.y.y.y.4241: Flags [.], cksum 0x01e6 (correct), ack 1, win 10880, options [nop,nop,TS val 984747 ecr 1043928682], length 0
>
> 17:29:43.890057 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 115, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
>       x.x.x.x.live.vodafone.in.43187 > y.y.y.y.4241: Flags [R], cksum 0xac3c (correct), seq 1477993783, win 65535, length 0

When I send the data to the server using netcap command, I do receive the data perfectly.

echo abctest-sumangala | nc y.y.y.y 4241 //I receive the bytes abctest-sumangala